# Determine effective permissions for another user in Python

Tags: python, permissions

My Python program (running on Ubuntu and OS X) places files in a `/tmp` directory and then instructs a running daemon process to read those files.

The daemon process runs under a different user and is not our code.

The daemon fails if it does not have read and execute permissions on the files, but it also needs read permission on the parent directory too.

I need to modify the Python program to check the permissions first and issue a warning to the user if the necessary permissions are not there - problem is the `os.access` function only evaluates permissions for the user running the Python process, I cannot see how to get effective-permissions for another user.

We also don't have access to the password for the daemon user's account so we can't simply launch a subprocess under that user-account to call `os.access` and return the result - though we are admin/root-capable users.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if

1.) The daemon user owns the file and has read+execute permissions

2.) The daemon user belongs to a group who owns the file and said group has read+execute permissions.

Or you can simply set the permissions of the file so that the daemon user is allowed to read+execute, thus guaranteeing axioms 1 and 2. This is probably the simplest method.

Below is some sample code to give you a starting point. I haven't run it or tested it.

```
import pwd, grp, os

DAEMON_USER = 'service-account' # unix user running the daemon
FILE_PATH = '/tmp/somefile.sh' # these are the files your'e putting in tmp

group_id_of_file = os.stat(FILE_PATH).st_gid # get id of group owner of the file
file_owner = pwd.getpwuid(os.stat(FILE_PATH).st_uid)
group_members = grp.getgrgid(group_id_of_file).gr_mem

group_permissions = oct(os.stat(FILE_PATH).st_mode)[5:6]
owner_permissions = oct(os.stat(FILE_PATH).st_mode)[4:5]
if (file_owner == DAEMON_USER and owner_permissions >= 5) or (DAEMON_USER in group_members and group_permissions >= 5):
  print "The daemon will be able to read and execute the file"
else:
  print "not good"
```